# Why @Using doesnt find PageList namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm following a tutorial to learn how to use the PageList in a MVC application.

In the CONTROLLER part works perfect with intellisense.

> using PagedList.Mvc;

But in the VIEW side say couldn't find namespace.
[image]

The weird part is after building the solution the error disapear and sample run ok.
But when I try to make change in the code the error reapear and I can't use the intellisense.

There are other errors regarding the use of the @Html.PagedListPager and also disapear after compile, and as I say all paging function works ok when I test the page.

> I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and C# 
>   add the Install-Package PagedList.Mvc
>   Installing 'PagedList 1.17.0.0'.
>   Installing 'PagedList.Mvc 4.5.0.0'.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but that kind of stuff happens to me now and then - I usually use the "Microsoft solution" - clean the solution, close and reopen Visual Studio - if that doesn't work, delete the suo and csproj.user files, delete Temporary ASP.NET Files, reboot machine, etc...Eventually after messing with it long enough, I usually get the error to go away. Since it runs fine, it tells me it's a problem with Visual Studio, not the compiler or ASP.NET itself.

Comment: @JoeEnos same happen to me more than once in my case Rebuild fix it. They are a lot of answers in the net about this which is really strange.

Comment: Ok, i will try creating a new project and let you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved.

First I open a new instance of VS2013, create a new Project and add the PagedList.Mvc package.

@using recognize the PagedList.Mvc namespace and intellisense was working fine too.

Then I was about to start the tutorial from beginning in this new Project and tought in @JoeEnos suggestion about try "Microsoft solution".

So I close and reopen my first project and now is also working fine.

Answer (score 0):

In controller

```
using PagedList;
using PagedList.MVC;
```

In view

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<YourModel>
@using PagedList;
@using PagedList.MVC;
```

Paging

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page =
page }))
```

Rebuild solution and it should work.

Comment: I didn't downvote. But as i try to explain I'm following a tutorial. The code is the same as you show and work after compile. My problem is I havent intellisense.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Like Joe Enos explain in his comment this happen sometimes, I don't know why too. In most cases I fix it with rebuild. If you want you can do it with clean and rebuild !

Comment: Thanks birth, i leave you a +1 to cancel the downvote :)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza just saying by Clean I mean - Build-Clean Solution and Rebuild I mean - Build->Rebiuld Solution